# What do you think is a better label "New" or "Add"

Tags: web-app, buttons, terminology, labels, wording

At the moment I am building a web application that stores a lot of data inside of tables. In each of the pages containing the tables the users have many actions; they can add, delete, or edit the data.

Right now all of my buttons for adding new data are labeled as "New", however I am starting to wonder which label would be better suited for this application. "New" or "Add"

Comment: Although "New" is inviting, "Add" is more direct as well as inviting!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're adding more items into a collection of items, then the term to go with is **Add**.

If the action is to create something totally new that isn't part of a clear collection, then I'd go with **New**.

Since you have tables where you can add data (a row collection where you add rows), I would use **Add** for inserting new rows of data. It's quite common in tabular data.

Comment: That is a great way to put it thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you're inside a list or another group of things "Add" would be appropriate since "New" may imply an entire new group.

But if your adding a new group of things "New " would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I think Add would be a better option because it implies that you're adding something to an already existing element, in this example a table. If you are creating a new table however, New would suit it better.